# python selenium how to get hover element information

Tags: python, selenium, hover

I need to get information from this [site](https://kalstall.de/) from the description using selenium python.
The description appears when you hover your mouse over the nickname.
I can't seem to find a way to get the description, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just grab all the values in the element div with id tip after you hover using ActionChains.

```
values=[x.text for x in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div#tip a")]
print(values)
```